# How to assign a value for specific Indeterminate expressions?

Tags: assignment, downvalues

I wanted to form a list as follows

```
j=1;
Table[(i-1-j)^k, {i,2j+1}, {k,-j,j}]
```

However, an error message occurred since the list included none positive powers of zero and the function produced

```
{{-1, 1, -1}, {ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

In my case, I want those values to be $0^0=1$ and $0^{-n}=0, n>0$ and the list should be

```
{{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

How can I assign the values to those expressions so that the `Table` function will produce the expected list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
j = 1;
Table[If[k == 0, 1, 
  If[i - 1 - j == 0 && k < 0, 0, (i - 1 - j)^k]], {i, 
  2 j + 1}, {k, -j, j}]
(*  {{-1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}  *)
```

Have fun!